# Shared responsibility model - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-rds

If an AWS customer store their business critical data in Amazon RDS instance sitting in private subnet of customer's default VPC.

How does AWS ensure privacy of this business critical data in RDS instance? In terms of exclusive access to AWS customer only....

Does AWS team not have access to this RDS instance data? How does "shared responsibility model" explain this compromise?

Answer (score 3):

There's a good amount of information available on this topic, including:

- [Security in RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.html)
- [Busting the Myths about Storing Data in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/publicsector/busting-the-myths-about-storing-data-in-the-cloud/) blog post, and [related whitepaper](https://aws.amazon.com/government-education/in-cloud-we-should-trust/).
- [Shared Responsibility Model](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/)
- [AWS Security Whitepaper](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/AWS_Security_Whitepaper.pdf)
- Third party discussion on the topic of [AWS data security](https://www.bridewellconsulting.com/aws-security-myths-part-1-data-security)